# JEditorPane incorrectly rendering HTML as plain text

Tags: java, swing

I've spent most of the day searching around SO/Google and trying variations on our code, all to no avail.  Nearly all of the example snippets I've seen use either setText() with HTML, or setPage() with a URL, which doesn't apply in our case.

The construction of the widget runs like this:

```
JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
pane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
pane.setContentType("text/html");
pane.setEditable(false);

generate_all_the_HTML_into(pane);

// put the pane into a scrolling dialog, pack() and show it, etc
```

The actual HTML gets generated in chunks; there's a Runnable getting fired off on a regular basis with the text to append, and a pointer to the JEditorPane.  The only catch is that its pointer is stored as a JTextComponent, so the Runnable's run() tries to operate generically:

```
// stored_text_component == pane
javax.swing.text.Document doc = stored_text_component.getDocument();
try {
    doc.insertString (doc.getLength(), the_new_string, null);
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    // this won't happen, but there's a bunch of code here in case it does
}
```

This all works in other situations, in which the stored_text_component is a JTextArea and we're just showing plain text.  And it works here too, as all the text being generated does show up in the displayed JEditorPane.

Except it all shows up as unformatted raw text, and I can't figure out why.

- I've tried reordering the setEditorKit() and setContentType() calls, no change.
- I've tried doing things like setDocument() using the kit's "create a default document", with no change.  It's no longer in the code because JEditorPane does that already internally, I've found.
- Tried writing "<html>" as the initial text.  No change, it just shows up as the first plain text in the window.

At the end of the first block of code, after showing the dialog, I tried dumping pane.getText() to a debug log.  It returns

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">

    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and *that* doesn't seem right at all.  Dumping out pane.getDocument().getText() returns an empty string.  These results would make me suspect that some data somewhere is getting completely lost... except that the text is indeed showing up in the window, it's just that JEditorPane loses its content settings somehow.

The HTML itself is extremely basic; we use similar routines to show markup inside a JLabel elsewhere.  But this is my first time messing with JEditorPane and the original author is long gone.

Comment: Try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org): a short, compilable, runnable and able to re-produce your problem for better help sooner

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I would have solved the problem.  Sorry.  :-(  I was hoping somebody with JEditorPane experience would recognize the symptoms.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll try kludging in JLabel instead of this JTextComponent nonsense.  JLabel has the nice property of Just Working when given HTML markup.